# How to iterate items in a list in python?

Tags: python

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4]
list2 = [7,8,9]
for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
        file = ('class{}_grade{}'.format(i,j))
```

now `file` = `class4_grade9`

How do I change my code so `file` is a list with 12 names?

Thanks

Comment: `file = [f'class{i}_grade{i}' for i in list1 for j in list2]`

Comment: create a list outside your loop, `file = []` then instead of `file = ('class{}_grade{}'.format(i,j))` use `file.append('class{}_grade{}'.format(i,j))`

Comment: Use `file.append()` to add to a list.

Comment: @Samwise if the OP is unaware of `.append`, maybe we should hold off on list comprehensions :)

Comment: let's also try and avoid recommending `file` as a variable name

Answer (score 2):

Currently file is a variable that can hold only one value. Each time the loop runs, that value is replaced.

You need to tell python

- It is a list
- To add the value to the existing list, rather than replace the list with the new value

```
file = []
list1 = [1,2,3,4]
list2 = [7,8,9]
for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
        file.append(('class{}_grade{}'.format(i,j)))
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you are setting `file` as a string and overwriting its value every loop. You have to make a list called `file` outside of the loop and append a new value to it every loop.

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4]
list2 = [7,8,9]
file = []
for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
        file.append(('class{}_grade{}'.format(i,j)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're new to programming, I recommend that you spell everything out rather than using variables like `list2` or `j`.  For example:

```
classes = [1, 2, 3, 4]
grades = [7, 8, 9]

filenames = []

for my_class in classes:
    for my_grade in grades:
        filenames.append(f"class{my_class}_grade{my_grade}")

print(*filenames, sep='\n')
```

Note how we change variable name `file` from a singular to a plural name now that it holds the names of *multiple* files.

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
class1_grade7
class1_grade8
class1_grade9
class2_grade7
class2_grade8
class2_grade9
class3_grade7
class3_grade8
class3_grade9
class4_grade7
class4_grade8
class4_grade9
>
```